# What's a book series, where they use precise time travel as a method of combat?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've heard of one before and I think the style of time travel fighting in it was called Temporal Flux but I'm not sure. So could anyone help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More details would help if you have them; time has been used as a weapon in many series...

That being said, something that leaps to mind is Temporal Fugue, from [Creatures of Light and Darkness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatures_of_light_and_darkness) by Roger Zelazny.  It involves being able to move to another nearby time, adding yourself to the causality loop; i.e., you basically copy yourself.  Extended temporal fugue battles can have hundreds of copies of each combatant, most of whom will be killed, but become irrelevant.

To steal from with Wikipedia page:

> The Steel General, Set, and some others practice a novel martial art called temporal fugue. A fighter, seeing that his enemy is ready to attack, projects himself behind his enemy—in both space and time—to strike him from behind. Of course, the enemy does the same thing. When both warriors use the technique, recursively, things get complicated. Each character is replicated over a hundredfold, at various times in the past and future, thus putting a considerable strain on the space-time continuum.

Comment: My thought as well. And Zelazny's book includes one of the most philosophically-interesting, theological monologues in all of literature.

Comment: You just gotta love the 'Possibly Proper Death Litany':

*Insofar as I may be heard by anything, which may or may not care what I say, I ask, if it matters, that you be forgiven for anything you may have done or failed to do which requires forgiveness. Conversely, if not forgiveness but something else may be required to ensure any possible benefit for which you may be eligible after the destruction of your body, I ask that this, whatever it may be, be granted or withheld, as the case may be, in such a manner as to insure your receiving said benefit.*

Comment: *I ask this in my capacity as your elected intermediary between yourself and that which may not be yourself, but which may have an interest in the matter of your receiving as much as it is possible for you to receive of this thing, and which may in some way be influenced by this ceremony.* -- Sometimes called the Agnostic's prayer.. Always one of my favorites :)

Answer (score 1):

Your description immediately reminded me of the [TimeWars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TimeWars) series by Simon Hawke.  I can't remember exactly, but I believe Temporal Fugue fights were part of this series.

[image: TimeWars]